# JS link 2 different templates for 2 different views of same list on 1 page

Tags: 2013, jslink, office-365

I have 1 list that I want to display in 2 different ways on the same page. When using the jslink property included in the OOTB listview webpart only one display template gets rendered for both webparts.

I'll use some example code from a blog post by Wes Preston, if anyone could show an example of how 2 of these display templates can be used together I can work from there.

template 1:

```
(function () {

//   Initialize the variables for overrides objects
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

//  alert("Override call worked");

//  Use BaseViewID and ListTemplateType to narrow focus/scope on 
//  which web parts on the page are affected
//  overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
//  overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

    /*
     * Using the Fields override leaves the rest of the rendering intact, but 
     * allows control over one or more specific fields in the existing view
     */
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'MoreText': { 'View' : 'Animal' }
    };

    /*
     * Register the template overrides.
     */
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
```

template 2:

```
(function () {

//   Initialize the variables for overrides objects
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

//  alert("Override call worked");

//  Use BaseViewID and ListTemplateType to narrow focus/scope on 
//  which web parts on the page are affected
//  overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
//  overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

    /*
     * Using the Fields override leaves the rest of the rendering intact, but 
     * allows control over one or more specific fields in the existing view
     */
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'MoreText': { 'View' : '<b><#=ctx.CurrentItem.MoreText#></b>' }
    };

    /*
     * Register the template overrides.
     */
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
```

Thanks.

Comment: see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113843/using-different-baseviewid-values-for-multiple-jslink-on-a-single-page/114129#114129

Comment: @Aveenav Thanks. This isn't the first time you've helped me with my js issues. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `BaseViewID` properties to different values, such as 99 and 98.  See [this](http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2013/09/listview-web-part-issues-with-jslink-and-display-templates-a-solution/) blog for more info.