# JSLink conflict with lists of the same type (List Custom 100)

Tags: display-template, jslink, client

## Problem

I've two custom lists with `ListTemplateType = 100`. When I insert both into a page, the last rewrite the first.

I tryed add `BaseViewID` with diferent ID, like [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115536/js-link-2-different-templates-for-2-different-views-of-same-list-on-1-page). But anything works with this property and is showed with default Sharepoint template.

#### Template 1 `app1-jslink.js`

```
;(function(){
    overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<div id='gallery-cardapio'>"+
            "<div class='gallery-cardapio'>"+
                "<ul class='thumbs'>";
    overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = CustomFooter;
    // overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1000; // Do not works
    overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

    overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

    function CustomItem(ctx){...}

    function CustomFooter(ctx){...}
})();
```

#### Template 2 `app2-jslink.js`

```
;(function(){
    overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<div id='gallery-niver'>"+
            "<div class='gallery-container'>"+
                "<ul class='thumbs'>";
    overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = CustomFooter;
    // overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 900; // Do not works
    overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

    overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

    function CustomItem(ctx){...}

    function CustomFooter(ctx){...}
})();
```

---

## Tests

If I put `BaseViewId` in just one, both templates are rendered with *override* that does not have `BaseViewId` property.

If I put `BaseViewId` in both, they are render with default Sharepoint template.

If I don't put `BaseViewId`, both are render with last  *override*.

---

### How fix it? How to use 2 diferent lists of type custom (100) in same page?

<sub><sub>Sorry, my english is not very good, and I've taken a bit help from Google Translate.</sub></sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough just to assign different `BaseViewId` values in your overrides, *you also have to set matching `BaseViewId` values to the web parts on the page*.

What you specify in the override is telling SharePoint: "this override applies when there are web parts that match the `ListTemplateType` *and* `BaseViewId` of what I set here."

If you do not change the `BaseViewId` value of the web parts themselves, they will stay as 1, and there will be no matches to your overrides.

So in your case, the behavior you saw was because both your web parts on the page still have `ListTemplateType = 100` and `BaseViewId = 1`, like this:

```
// override code for template 1
overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;
overrideCtx.BaseViewId = 1000;

// override code for template 2
overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;
overrideCtx.BaseViewId = 99;

//...

// web part 1 on page
ctx.ListTemplateType = 100;
ctx.BaseViewId = 1;

// web part 2 on page
ctx.ListTemplateType = 100;
ctx.BaseViewId = 1;
```

In the above case there were no matches, so both web parts render with default rendering.

```
// override code for template 1
overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;
// overrideCtx.BaseViewId = 1000; // commented out, so base view id will be 1

// override code for template 2
overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;
overrideCtx.BaseViewId = 99;

//...

// web part 1 on page
ctx.ListTemplateType = 100;
ctx.BaseViewId = 1;

// web part 2 on page
ctx.ListTemplateType = 100;
ctx.BaseViewId = 1;
```

This time, both web parts match the override settings for template 1, so both will render as template 1.

What you have to do is hijack the code where SharePoint is rendering the web parts initially, and set their `BaseViewId`s to match the ones you use in the template overrides.

Read through this article very carefully:
http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2013/09/listview-web-part-issues-with-jslink-and-display-templates-a-solution/

He outlines a way to hijack the rendering at the right time to be able to see which web part is rendering, and set it to have the `BaseViewId` that you want it to have so it will match your override.

Comment: Yeah! This works! I put the function `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` with my `wpq`s in a web part script editor on top of my page and the `BaseViewId` on my `ctx` object and works... :D Thanks!